# Pause a Macro, Edit sheet, and Resume without buttons

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that needs to be run for many workbooks. There is a part though where I update a segment of the connection string with unique values and apparently this can't be done in VBA so I must manually do it. Is there a way I can have the Macro do what it does then pause while I update the connection string for say 30 seconds then start running again to completion?
Thanks,

Comment: Not sure if I follow the problem here .. why do you need to update connection string again? Why can't it be parametrized?

Comment: The reason why is cause this macro opens and adjusts multiple workbooks that each uses a unique number in the connection string to query the SQL table. So in the connection string I need to update all dates to 1/1/2014 but also in that same string there is a unique number to each workbook to pull in the proper information. If there is a way you can think of to do that that would be even more helpful but I haven't found anything yet where I can just update a section of the connection string. Only thing I found updates the whole connection string which wouldn't allow the unique ID # to pull in

Comment: the proper information in each separate workbook as it would only have the ID of the workbook the macro was originally written for. as far as I can tell there is no way to just edit a portion of a connection string to just change the date from 2013 to 2014 and leave everything else in the string the same way it already is.

Comment: We may be able to find a solution like what @PankajJaju is suggesting, if you were to post your code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a macro that will allow you 30 seconds to make changes and then resume operation:

```
Sub dural()
    'first part
    'do stuff
    MsgBox "Perform updates"
    t1 = Now
    While Now < t1 + TimeSerial(0, 0, 30)
        DoEvents
    Wend
    MsgBox "Resuming the second part of the macro"
    'macro does more stuff
End Sub
```

**NOTE**:

the **DoEvents** allows focus to be shared with the user.

Comment: That is what I was looking for thank you alot. Also, if you could read the other comment I wrote in this string, that is the real problem I am trying to solve but cannot find a solution for so i've opted to just pause the macro and do it myself. However if you know a solution to automate that it would be even better. Thanks though so much for your help.